# When can I feel comfortable to ask a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette, scope, too-broad

I always have questions! I keep a notepad with me most all times to jot down sudden ideas and thoughts that I can delegate away.

When I go to looking at my notepad of things I'd love to know more about, specific or broad... I let it sit.
Basically, I am uncomfortable with wasting some very helpful peoples time!

---

Usually the questions I have are more broad, like "what math would I need to know to direct traffic in space" is one of them. Sometimes I think they're really specific, but then I can't find a duplicate because I don't know what to search for...
<strike>There's an anxiety element to this, I suppose, but I just hate to waste people's time, especially on a big site that has a whole "meta" site to discussing interactions on the site.</strike>

---

My question is hard to parse, and its likely there's more than one in there, but, reiterating the title differently:

**What should I do on StackExchange to feel "I can post this question correctly"?**

and maybe, additionally:

- Is there a place I can ask more broad, open-ended questions,
- is there a place where I can ask about what to ask about, and
- is there a place where I can ask how to learn to have understanding up to an idea of mine?

Comment: You can start by using Google or Bing to do your own research, to narrow the scope of the question. Break it into subsets if need be, but *do some serious research* first before asking at any of the [se] sites. It's amazing what you can learn by spending some time with your favorite search engine, and many of the results will lead you to something already asked on a [se] site. We don't do broad, open-ended questions on any of the [se] technical sites, so regardless of the site you need to *do some research yourself first* to narrow down the scope of the question.

Comment: The answers for this question cover your first and third questions pretty well -- I would just add a point regarding your second question. If you're not sure what site to ask a question on, you can write up a brief outline of the question here, and ask a question with the tag [tag:site-recommendation].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a place I can ask more broad, open-ended questions

Broad questions tend to be on a per-site basis.  Some sites consider some things too broad, others don't.  I'll point to the recent public beta of [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) that has questions, that, well, coming from a SO background seem to be too broad... but apparently they work well there.  Each site is different.

Be sure to read the help center on each site you think of to see if its appropriate or not for topicality.

> is there a place where I can ask about what to ask about

Chat.  Each site has its own chat room(s).  Stack Overflow has many, most other sites just have one main one.  The people there are often able to either help direct you to the proper site, or help you craft a good question, or help answer the too broad question.

For example, the traffic control for space?  That woulds like something to look at Space Exploration.  Their chat room is [The Pod Bay](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9682/the-pod-bay).  It's a rather quiet room, but still appears to have decent activity from time to time.  Note that on smaller sites with less activity, the mods for the site tend to be the ones most active in the room (larger sites tend to have people more active than the mods, but still able to help).

You can find the chat room by going to the site, selecting the Stack Exchange drop down, and then clicking on 'chat' next to the site itself.

[image: How to find chat]

> is there a place where I can ask how to learn to have understanding up to an idea of mine?

The 'what do I need to learn' is often a very broad subject and on sites with narrower scopes often finds a corresponding close reason.  Again, ask in chat and you might get some helpful information there that would point you in the right direction.

Comment: I had no idea there was a chat room option! I'll go to this often, thank you

Answer (score 3):

- Find out all you can about the topic first.  Write yourself specific questions - and with your increased understanding, ask these as questions - when you hit a wall - that's when you should ask here.
- But first, be sure to read and absorb the Tour and Help pages of any site of interest.  Also read questions and answers that are both positively and negatively received (rep) to gauge what is acceptable and not acceptable respectively on the site.
- Broad, open ended questions generally get put 'on hold' (it is a closing reason) - we prefer specific questions that can be answered.

Your last two additional questions are unclear to me. Asking what to ask about - that would be on the 'Tour' and 'Help' pages of each site.  As for understanding the ideas, that would require a well-written, specific question that is relevant to one of the sites.

Generally, if an answer is put on hold, comments about what specifically is the problem are attached - more often than not referring to the Help pages.